# Count Rows If Column A OR Column B meet criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck trying to count the number of rows that meet a certain criteria. I have a large database in excel. Now on column A and B, I have a lot of text in cell, but I want to count every row if cell A or B meets my criteria.

Let's say column A has some notes from the morning and column B from the afternoon, and every rows represents a day. Now, let's say I want to count how many days I have mentioned "shopping", morning or evening. I would need a function like this:

```
// COUNTIF_OR(<range_1>,<criteria_1>,<range_2>,<criteria_2>)
COUNTIF_OR(A1:A100;"*shopping*";B1:B100;"*shopping*")
```

Most solution I could find on the internet counts the rows if A `AND` B meet the criteria, instead of A `OR` B.

Please, help me!

Comment: COUNTIF_OR()? COUNTIF() or COUNTIFS() and then include OR() as a constraint.

Comment: Could you expand on your question and be more clear with sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your two columns are contiguous, you could use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("shopping",A1:B100))),{1;1})>0))`

though I would be tempted by:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"=";"<>";"="}&"*shopping*",B:B,{"<>";"=";"="}&"*shopping*"))`

which, notwithstanding its rather obtuse nature and the fact that it is not readily extendible to more than two columns, does nevertheless mean that you can continue to employ `COUNTIFS` and so benefit from referencing entire columns (`A:A`, `B:B`) with virtually no detriment to calculation performance (which cannot be said for the `SUMPRODUCT`/`MMULT` set-up).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is Very helpful! The second formula works better for me, because I have also columns that are not neighbous (like col A and col G) that needs to be checked.